# Automatically creating type of method

Tags: c#, dry

How can I automatically initialize the type of a method in C#?

For instance,

```
List<int> MyIntList()
{
    List<int> returnList = new List<int>();
    return returnList;
}
```

I've basically created an instance of the return type, to return. Is there something in the C# language that infers the type to return, so that an instance doesn't have to be created within the method, such as:

```
List<int> MyIntList()
{
    // invalid - "this" refers to the containing class,
    // but looking for something that refers to the containing method.
    this = new List<int>();
    return this;
}
```

Simply put, can I prevent `List<int>` in the example from being typed more than once, and let the compiler infer the rest?

Comment: I use `List<int>` as an example - the question holds for any type, generic or not.

Comment: This seems like an X-Y question. Why do you want to do this? What is the intended use?

Comment: What if the method return type was an abstract class?

Comment: You need to grab CLR Via C# and start reading from chapter 4.  You won't regret it.

Comment: Sorry, I know this looks at first like it doesn't make sense - but it's a syntax question. Is there a syntax element that refers to the containing method?

Comment: But *why* do you need to do that? It seems like you may need some kind of generic method.

Comment: You won´t need a reference to the method itself in order to set its return-value. This is already done by *returning*  a value.

Comment: You can use `out`/`ref` parameters to pass in something what you don't have to create, the caller have to create/pass those.

Comment: As to the question of "why" - it's because I've repeated in code at least twice (even with `var` keyword) what type is expected. I'd like to not repeat myself, and honestly I don't understand why it's necessary, unless the language specification just simply requires it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like

```
auto MyIntList()
{
    return new List<int>();
}
```

Having the compiler infer the return value and replace `auto` with `List<int>`

This is not possible with the latest version of C# (6.0)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm talking about. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting, is there a reference to `auto`? I can't find one (only for `C++`). It looks like a right thing to lazy programmer, similar to `var`.

Comment: `auto` does not exist for C#. I used the word `auto` in order not to confuse with other existing C# keywords. `C++14` can infer the return type using the `auto` keyword though.

Comment: plus 1 for "lazy programmer" - perhaps I should have given that as the reason for the question!

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly you mean something like this:

```
List<int> MyIntList()
{
    var result = new List<int>();
    return result;
}
```

`var` is just a placeholder for the actual type `List<int>` or whatever you assign to it. In contrast to JavaScript in C# the keyword relate to a strong type so you can deal with it as with any other type, it automatically lists the correct members appropriate for that type.

EDIT: To answer why you can´t do what you want: The method-signature often states that an interface is returned, however the actual type doesn´t matter at all. Usually you won´t care if the method actually returns a `List`, a `Dictionary` or anything else as long as it implements `IEnumerable` for example. However if you´d force the compiler to return a `List<int>` instead of an `IEnumerable<int>` for example you lose all the benfits of interfaces as you allways infer the actual type insteaf of the interface. Having said this the consumer of the mthod could even add or remove elements from/to the list being returned. If you´d use the mentioned interface all you return is something that represents a list of values which can be enumerated.

Also consider this case:

```
List<int> MyIntList()
{
    if (anyCondition)
    {
        var result = new List<int>();
        return result;
    }
    else 
    {
        var result = new int[0];
        return result
    }
}
```

What type should the compiler infer in this case? The signature of the method is a contract to the outside which determines which things you can do with the result.

Comment: Ah, of course. Yep, that helps. But I wonder if there's such a thing as a reference to the containing method?

Comment: Why should you need this? You have a value which you want to return. Doesn´t this automatically imply a two-step logic, first get the value, secondly return it?

Comment: the question is about syntax the compiler expects. Look how many times `List<int>` is repeated in the example provided by this answer. Why not just specify once, and be done?

Comment: In this case you might use the `dynamic`-keyword. However you´ll use type-safety in this case which isn´t recommended usually.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this:

```
private static T GetSomething<T>() where T: new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

But then you will need to pass the type as typeparameter `T`:

```
var x = GetSomething<List<int>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a precise answer as to whether the C# specification disallows it, but I can provide examples.  First, what if you want a method to return an interface?  In your examples you used `List<int>` but what if you changed it to `IList<int>`?  Or consider this simplified example:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}
public class Foo1 : IFoo
{
    public Foo1() { }
    public void Bar() => Console.WriteLine("Foo1.Bar");
}
public class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    private Foo2() { }
    public static Foo2 Create => new Foo2();
    public void Bar() => Console.WriteLine("Foo2.Bar");
}
```

You cannot create an instance of an interface.  So this is wrong:

```
public IFoo BadFooCreate() => new IFoo(); // won't compile
```

But this would work, though it begs the question of how the compiler know you want Foo1 to be the particular IFoo that is returned:

```
public IFoo GoodFooCreate() => new Foo1(); // compiles okay
```

This works too:

```
public IFoo GoodFooCreate() => Foo2.Create(); // compiles okay
```

But since Foo2 has a private constructor, this would not work:

```
public IFoo BadFoo2Create() => new Foo2(); // won't compile
```

Another set of examples revolve around abstract classes.  Consider:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public Animal() { }
    public virtual string Name => "Generic Animal";
    public abstract string Speak();
}
public class Dog : Animal
{
    public override string Name => "Dog";
    public override string Speak() => "Bark";
}
public class Cat : Animal
{
    public override string Name => "Cat";
    public override string Speak() => "Meow";
}
```

This would be wrong because you can't create an instance of an abstract class:

```
public Animal BadAnimalCreate() => new Animal(); // won't compile
```

But this works perfectly fine:

```
public Animal GoodAnimalCreate() => new Dog(); // compiles okay
```

Although again if the compiler were to automatically create a type for a lazy programmer, how would the compiler know to use Dog() and not Cat()?  Letting the compiler pick on your behalf encroaches on violating the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).  There's being lazy and then there's abdicating your responsibility.